# How best to write a __str__ method for my tree class?

Tags: python, class, methods, tree

I have a class named `Tree`:

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, tag, children):
        self.tag = tag
        self.children = children
    def __str__(self):
        pass
```

This is an example object of my class:

```
tree = Tree('A', [Tree('B', [Tree('C', [])]), Tree('D', [Tree('E', [])])])
```

Now I want that when I print my tree, that it looks like the following:

`(A (B C) (D E))`

My thoughts are to loop through the nested Trees and check until I find an empty list, which tells me that this empty list belongs to one of my leaves of the tree. And then I built it from there upwards and add parentheses around my tags and children.

Comment: There is no question here. There is no problem here, other than: this needs to be implemented, but it still is not. Have you tried something?

Comment: You just have to issue a `print()` command under __str__()

Perhaps something like print( " ".join([self.tag]+self.children) )

Comment: Rather `return  " ".join([self.tag]+self.children)`

Answer (score 1):

An iterative approach would probably work, but I think recursive is more appropriate here.

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, tag, children):
        self.tag = tag
        self.children = children

    def __str__(self):
        # Recursively build up the full string
        if self.children:
            return f'({self.tag} {" ".join(str(child) for child in self.children)})'
        # Base case - no children; Just return the tag.
        else:
            return self.tag
```

This will then produce the string you want:

```
>>> tree = Tree('A', [Tree('B', [Tree('C', [])]), Tree('D', [Tree('E', [])])])
>>> print(tree)
(A (B C) (D E))
```

---

IMO, it would make more sense to keep sub-children grouped in their own parentheses like this (additional "F" node added for clarity):

```
(A (B (C)) (D (E)) (F))
```

which you can do by wrapping the `else` return in parentheses:

```
class Tree:
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        ...
        else:
            return f'({self.tag})'
```

But of course, it's up to you if that's correct for your usage or not :)